# How to Set Month & Year to Jquery Datepicker which has only Month & Year Selection via selenium execute Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

[image]

I tried using webelement._flatpickr.setDate("05/1990",true);

But its not working.

Comment: the input tag has these following classes. calender-icon lsq-flatpickr-to-init  flatpickr-date